# Dynamically user control inside update panel disappear after click button inside this user control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

When click the button inside the user control it seems its not do its event (button click)
I just want reload the update panel and this user control take the new effect in this button click event

I add user control on html control inside the update panel like this

```
<!-- language: c# -->
content.Controls.Remove(content.FindControl("currentusercontrol"));
    UserControl usr1 = (UserControl)LoadControl("myusercontrol.ascx");
    usr1.ID = "currentusercontrol";
   content.Controls.Add(usr1);
```

And this my parent page content

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True"> </asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load" OnPreRender="UpdatePanel1_PreRender">

        <ContentTemplate>

    <div id="content" class="content" runat="server">
        <!-- begin breadcrumb -->

        <!-- end breadcrumb -->
        <!-- begin page-header -->
        <h1 class="page-header" runat="server" id="pageheader">Dashboard v2 <small id="smallheader" runat="server">header small text goes here...</small></h1>
        <!-- end page-header -->

    </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>           
        </Triggers>           
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is my user control page

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Contact_Us" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<script runat="server">
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Label1.Text = "lion";
}
</script>

<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_OnClick"  />
```

i try this but its not work

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
```

I tried to put trigger directly to update panel but I had error there is no control with this id because button is in user control so  I tried to put the trigger programmatically on user control load event 
Like this

```
    UpdatePanel UpdatePanel1 = this.Parent.FindControl("UpdatePanel1") as UpdatePanel;
    AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    trigger.ControlID = Button1.ID;
    trigger.EventName = "Click";
    UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

But I have same error
control with ID 'Button1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

then itried to use client id for button1 like this

```
trigger.ControlID = Button1.ClientID;
```

same problem 
A control with ID 'currentusercontrol_Button1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Comment: You have to add dynamic controls every time your page is loaded. They aren't stored in viewstate.

Comment: thanks alot but the problem is my page not load every time , I have a menu and every time menu item click I refresh the content inside update panel with new user control

Answer (score 0):

Modify what you want inside Update Panel (via asp tags ID's) at button click and call UpdatePanel1.Update();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is button click not fire , when I click the button the user control is just disappear I need to refresh the user control inside update panel only with new effect

Comment: Use protected or public instead of `private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Label1.Text = "lion";
}`

Comment: I tried them both but no change still button click not fire and user control disappear

Comment: Ok, here you have two option:                                                             1. button trigger wrapped inside `<ContentTemplate>` or use                                                             2. `<Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
            </Triggers>` in both cases use on click handler  UpdatePanel1.Update();

Comment: I try it but trigger directly to update panel,I had error there is no control with this id because button is in user control so  I tried to put the trigger programmatically on user control load event 
Like this
        UpdatePanel UpdatePanel1 = this.Parent.FindControl("UpdatePanel1") as UpdatePanel;
        AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = Button1.ID;
        trigger.EventName = "Click";
        UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger);
I have same error
control with ID 'Button1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Answer (score 0):

i found it i just put this code inside updatepanel load and all thing went fine

```
        content.Controls.Remove(content.FindControl("currentusercontrol"));
        UserControl usr1 = (UserControl)LoadControl("myusercontrol");
        usr1.ID = "currentusercontrol";
        content.Controls.Add(usr1);
```